# What is a shinigami representative?

Tags: bleach

So I just finished *Bleach* at episode 366 (dubbed) and I know that you are supposed to pick up at chapter 480. However, I have no idea what some of the phrases mean, like "shinigami representative".

What does it mean by "shinigami representative"?

Comment: could you offer any context as to where that wording was used?

Comment: if i remember, shinigami representative has literal meaning, not a real shinigami but the representative like ichigo

Answer (score 1):

That would be the beauty of different/fan translations, in that one sentence could be translated into several different sentences in the other language and effectively mean the same thing. This is especially prevalent for names or titles which don't have quite as direct translations.

Shinigami representative is one potential translation of 死神代行 (Shinigami Daikō) which google translate directly translates to Shinigami Actor, Shinigami meaning God of death or Death God. I believe the official translation called it a Substitute Shinigami, the title bestowed to Ichigo, which comes with that sweet hollow detector and soul expelling pass.